# How would I extract any word after second hyphen in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', '0'],
               'B': ['0xF188-abc-cde', '0xF188-abc-abcde', '0xF188-abc-1234', '0xF188-abc-tu231er']})
```

Now I want to add NEW column "EXTRACT" which is an extraction of column 'B' after second hyphen.

Below is the Expected Column.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', '0'],
               'B': ["0xF188-abc-cde", '0xF188-abc-abcde', '0xF188-abc-1234', '0xF188-abc-tu231er'],
                    'Extract':['cde', 'abcde', '1234', 'tu231er']})
```

Comment: After the 2nd hyphen or after the last hyphen? (and what if there's no hyphens or not two hyphens etc..?)

Comment: There will always be minimum 2 hyphen and yes it can be increased to 3 0r 4 or more. So its better to say After last hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply a function to split the column `B` using `-` and then extract the last element using `[-1]`:

```
df['Extract'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])
```

Output:

```
   A                   B  Extract
0  a      0xF188-abc-cde      cde
1  b    0xF188-abc-abcde    abcde
2  c     0xF188-abc-1234     1234
3  0  0xF188-abc-tu231er  tu231er
```

Another method as suggested by @sophocles :

```
df['Extract'] = df.B.str.split('-').str[-1]
```

Comment: no need for ```apply```, ```df.B.str.split('-').str[-1]```, right?